# How to configure Magento 2 multiple websites on AWS EC2

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website, multidomain, aws

I have an an Apache web server running on AWS EC2 instance serving a fresh Magento 2.3 installation. I want this one M2 instance to serve multiple stores across multiple domains.
For example:
www.coolbooks.com -> serves coolBooks store
www.coolTshirts.com -> serves coolTshirts store
Apache on that one Ec2 server should serve those two domains.

I know how to set up the different websites and stores on the Magento admin site, but I am clueless on how to configure this via Apache and AWS.

I have read and follow the related documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html) but that did not work for me. It would redirect me to these domains in the browser but did not serve any pages. I suspect DNS issues.

Is there a way to do this?